# Joint distribution involving Brownian motion and running maximum

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

As we know, the joint distribution of standard Brownian motion $B_t$ and its running maximum $M_t=\sup_{s\in[0,t]} B_s$ is given by
$$P(B_t\in da,M_t\in db)=\frac{2(2b-a)}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}e^{-\frac{(2b-a)^2}{2t}}da\,db$$
What is the joint distribution of $B_t$ and $M_t(M_t-B_t)$, i.e., how to compute $P(B_t\in da,M_t(M_t-B_t)\in dc)$?

---

I have tried some formal way like solving $M_t$ by letting $B_t=da$ in $M_t(M_t-B_t)=dc$, then I get $M_t=(da+\sqrt{(da)^2+4dc})/2$. I let $db=(da+\sqrt{(da)^2+4dc})/2$ in the given formula, and I cannot proceed.

Comment: Hint : use the joint distribution of $B_t$ and $M_t$ and integrate to get $\mathbb P(B_t\le a, M_t(M_t-B_t)\le c)\,.$ ( Not sure though if that has a closed form solution ). Then differentiate w.r.t. $a$ and $c$.

Comment: Hard to obtain the first step.